# Verify the value of fields of a collection in Laravel with "when" and omit the results if certain conditions are true

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I want to omit values to users if certain conditions apply. My table `advertisements` has a few flag fields, and one of them is an option to allow only users marked as trusted by the user will be able to see the ad. As for the trusted users, the information is stored in a table saving the ID of the user who blocked and the blocked user.

```
id    |    trusted_by_user_id    |   user_id
---------------------------------------------------------
1                           1                             2
```

If the option is marked before creating the ad, the value will be `1`. Now, I know about `when`, but I'm confused because how will it see that `trusted_by_user_id` is one, and then perform another operation to compare the logged in user's ID to the `user_id` in the `trusts` table?

```
...
$ads = $ads->whereDoesntHave('user.blocks', function ($q) {
    $q->where('user_id', '=', Auth::id());
})->when(1, function ($q1, $t) {
    return $q1->whereHas('user.trusts', function ($q2) use ($q1) {
        $q1->where('trusted_people_only' === $q2->user_id);
    });
})->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');
```

The `whereDoesntHave` is easier because it applies to all. But in the case of `trusted_people_only` being set to `1`, it will display only to the users marked as trusted, as in the table above. Otherwise, it will show to everybody.

The `User` model has the following relationship:

```
public function trusts() {
    return $this->hasMany(Trust::class, 'trusted_by_user_id');
}
```

More attempts

```
$ads = $ads->whereDoesntHave('user.blocks', function ($q) use ($auth) {
    $q->where('user_id', '=', $auth->id);
})->whereHas('user.trusts', function ($q1) use ($auth) {
    $q1->when(1, function ($q2) use ($auth) {
        return $q2->select('user_id')->from('trusts');
    });
})->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');
```

It either returns all the results or none. I am logged in with a third user of id `3`, and one of the results has the flag `1` and the creator trusts the user id `2`, but still is seen by the third one.

Comment: if you dont want rows with certain user ids, you can use whereNotIn

Answer (score 0):

Ok, since my solution for this was [using cursors](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#chunking-results) because I believe it was more complex to be used only with `when` and `whereHas` etc.

This is the code that successfully would allow me to, as a user that is trusted, to see ads created by the user A who trusts user B, but not by the user C. Simply check if the flag is true, then compare the logged in user `id` with the id of the user who is trusted. If it is different, restart the loop with `continue`.

```
public function all()
{
    $allAds = [];
    $auth = Request::user('api');

    $ads = Advertisement::with('user.trusts')
        ->whereHas('user', function ($q) {
            $q->where('country', '=', Request::route("locale"));
        });

    if ($auth) {
        $ads = $ads->whereDoesntHave('user.blocks', function ($q) use ($auth) {
            $q->where('user_id', '=', $auth->id);
        })->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');

        foreach ($ads->cursor() as $k => $v) {
            $ad = $ads->get()[$k];
            $trustedOnly = $ad->trusted_people_only === 1;

            if ($trustedOnly && $ad->user->trusts[0]->user_id !== $auth->id) {
                continue;
            }

            array_push($allAds, $ad);
        }
    } else {
        $allAds = $ads->get();
    }

    return Response::json(['ads' => $allAds], HTTPResponse::$HTTP_OK);
}
```